# How to make Background of Image Invisible?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

SO I need it to be simple way of telling of another way of make the background of the image clear, because I use the magic want tool (fuzzy select tool) and tried to make the background clear, it just make it white and not transparent so is there an alternative way to make the background of the image clear?

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate the layer so its not a locked background layer. Then delete the original locked background layer. Then do the same thing you did previously and it'll be transparent (shown as a grey grid).

Comment: You can also just drag the lock icon to the trash, which will save you the duplicate/delete steps.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the problem is that photoshop is assuming the document base is white and not transparent, to solve this:

1. Create a new document and make sure that the background for the image is 'Transparent' instead of white
2. Copy and paste the image into that document on a new layer
3. Repeat the magic wand tool selection as you did before and remove the areas you don't want.
4. When saving, make sure you save the file in a format that supports transparency for example GIF, PNG

That should sort your problem

Answer (score 0):

You just need to Double click on the background layer and it turns to normal layer
then you can clear it

the background layer on it self could not be transparent. but you can delete the background or change it type to normal layer by double click on it.

good luck